# Accessing fopen from a class in PHP

Tags: php

For some reason I'm having trouble accessing the `fopen()` function from inside a class in PHP:

```
<?php

    class Compare
    {
        function __construct( ){  }

        private $q_scores = array();

        private $q_path = "./data/questions.txt";

        private $questions = fopen($q_path, 'r');   

        //...

    }

?>
```

How do I access the built-in php functions from inside the class?

Many thanks

Comment: What trouble are you having? What error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this line in the constructor (it's made for this)

```
$this->questions = fopen($this->q_path, 'r');
```

And simply declare it like:

```
private $questions;
```

Comment: I've got rid of the error message from the IDE, but I keep getting 500 HTTP error when I run this code in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try to open it in `__construct()`

```
<?php

    class Compare
    {
        private $q_scores = array();
        private $q_path = "./data/questions.txt";
        private $questions;
        function __construct( ){  
            $this->questions = fopen($this->q_path, 'r');
              echo $this->questions;
        }
    }
$a = new Compare;
?>
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d3fcd.php)

Comment: You cannot declare private variables inside the constructor