# Problem accessing text file in a class in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php

    class Compare
    {
        private $questions;

        private $q_scores = array();

        private $q_path = "data/questions.txt";

        function __construct( )
        {  
            ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE); 
            $this->questions = fopen($this->q_path, 'r');  
        }

        public function checkStringForProximity($string)
        {
            while ($line = fgets($questions))
            {
                echo $line;
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

This relates to my prev. question: [Accessing fopen from a class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770170/accessing-fopen-from-a-class-in-php)

The problem is that `$line` never prints and I don't know why.

I use this class by using:

```
$compare = new Compare();

$compare->checkStringForProximity("string");
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
while ($line = fgets($questions))
```

`$questions` does not exist. It should be replaced with `$this->questions`

Comment: Thanks for that... Of course forgot to try `$this` object reference.